# Customer Address attribute added in grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, customer-address, customer-grid, customer-address-attribute

I have added one customer address custom attribute. it is showing in the customer address form as a dropdown field. Now I want to show that as a column in customer address grid in admin with value.

I have added this code:

```
<column name="addresstype" class="xxx\xxx\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Address\Column\Addresstype" sortOrder="95">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">addresstype</label>
            <editor>
                <editorType>text</editorType>
            </editor>
        </settings>
    </column>
```

The column is added but the value is not showing in this. how to get the value which was set in form? I tried in the following way, but getting an error:

xxx/xxx/Customer/Ui/Component/Listing/Address/Column/Addresstype.php

```
 public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource): array
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {

            if ($item['addresstype'] == 1) {
                $item['addresstype'] = 'Yes';
            } else {
                $item['addresstype'] = 'No';
            }
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}
```

But i ma getting error :

```
Undefined index: addresstype in /var/www/html/zest-anchor/app/code/Zest/Integration/Customer/Ui/Component/Listing/Address/Column/Addresstype.php on line 75 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index: addresstype in /var/www/html/zest-anchor/app/code/Zest/Integration/Customer/Ui/Component/Listing/Address/Column/Addresstype.php on line 75 at /var/www/html/zest-anchor/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

To get your value in the admin grid, the code should be

`in your ui_component xml file`

```
<column name="addresstype" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="95">
            <settings>
                <addField>true</addField>
                <options class="Zest\Integration\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\AddressType"/>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Address Type</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
```

You dont need a source class as its a customer address attribute, check your customer address attribute settings, make sure you have set `Yes`  for `Add to Column Options` and `Use in Filter Options`

<strike>In your customer address type source file</strike>

<strike>`Zest\Integration\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\AddressType.php`</strike>

```
<?php

namespace Zest\Integration\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\SourceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

/**
 *  returns customer's address type source
 *
 */
class AddressType extends AbstractSource implements SourceInterface, OptionSourceInterface
{
    
   
    /**
     * Retrieve option array
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public static function getOptionArray()
    {
        return [ 0 => __('No'), 1 => __('Yes')];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option array with empty value
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $result[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option text by option value
     *
     * @param string $optionId
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOptionText($optionId)
    {
        $options = self::getOptionArray();

        return isset($options[$optionId]) ? $options[$optionId] : null;
    }

}
```

To get your option values in the grid for `select` type columns , you need an `attribute source class` like the one above

To modify the value in the grid you need a `renderer class` like the one that you've added in the question.

Comment: but how to get value from renderer class. like if i added this code.. only yes value is visible... its not change
            if ($item['addresstype'] == 1) {
                $item['addresstype'] = 'Yes';
            } else {
                $item['addresstype'] = 'No';
            }

Comment: if i use your above code.. i am getting error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.addresstype' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `main_table`.`addresstype` FROM `customer_address_entity` AS `main_table` WHERE (`parent_id` = '103674') LIMIT 20 {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.addresstype' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `main_table`.`addresstype` FROM `customer_address_entity` AS `main_table` WHERE (`parent_id` = '103674') LIMIT 20

Comment: Hi, in your case, you don't need a source class, as its a customer address attribute and it shows up in the `address edit form` already. How did you add the address attribute. through backend or through setup class ? if from backend, check your attribute settings, make sure you have set `Yes`  for `Add to Column Options` and `Use in Filter Options`

Comment: @Haijerome I have added Add to Column Options = true and use in filter = true, still customer address attribute value is not visible in customer grid, however customer attribute working fine, I am using magento 2.2.11. any idea?